# How to change part of text color in webview dynamically in android

Tags: android

Am using viewpager and fragments to show webviews in horizontal scroll.In webview am filling dynamic text.I want to change the part of text color(not the enite webview's content only particular part) in that webview dynamically and also i want to autoscroll webview?Please help me

```
public  class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("count in getCount() is" + channelsItemList.size());

            return channelsItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        System.out.println("in getItem and position is" + position);

        WebViewFragment fragment = new WebViewFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("heading", channelsItemList.get(position));
        args.putString("data",channelsItemList.get(position));

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       return POSITION_NONE;
```

}
}

Here is the fragment code:
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment  {

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;


 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_fragment, container,
 false);

 WebView articleData = (WebView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.artWebView);
TextView headingData = (TextView)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.artHeading);
    String content = getArguments().getString("data");

     String artContent = "<html><head>"
              + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{ color: black;}"
              + "</style></head>"
              + "<body>"                          
              + content
              + "</body></html>";

    String data = getArguments().getString("heading");
     articleData.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     articleData.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
     articleData.loadDataWithBaseURL("", artContent, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

// articleData.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    // articleData.loadData(artContent, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
//   articleData.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, artContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

     articleData.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             return true;
         }
     });









     return layoutView;
 }
```

}

Comment: Could you, please, attach your code?

Comment: hi attached the code

Comment: Please some one help me